# Use of OR as branch control in FP

Tags: python, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I undertook an interview last week in which I learnt a few things about python I didn't know about (or rather realise how they could be used), first up and the content of this question is the use of `or` for the purposes of branch control.

So, for example, if we run:

```
def f():
    # do something. I'd use ... but that's actually a python object.

def g():
    # something else.

f() or g()
```

Then if `f()` evaluates to some true condition then that value is returned, if not, `g()` is evaluated and whatever value it produces is returned, whether true or false. This gives us the ability to implement an `if` statement using `or` keywords.

We can also use `and` such that `f() and g()` will return the value of `g()` if `f()` is true and the value of `f()` if `g()` is false.

I am told that this (the use of `or` for branch control) is a common thing in languages such as lisp (hence the lisp tag). I'm currently following [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) learning Scheme, so I can see that `(or (f x) (g x))` would return the value of `(g x)` assuming `(f x)` is `#f`.

I'm confused as to whether there is any advantage of this technique. It clearly achieves branch control but to me the built in keywords seem more self-explanatory.

I'm also confused as to whether or not this is "functional"? My understanding of pure functional programming is that you use constructs like this (an example from my recent erlang experiments):

```
makeeven(N,1) -> N+1;
makeeven(N,0) -> N;
makeeven(N)   -> makeeven(N,N rem 2).
```

Or a better, more complicated example using [template meta-programming in C++](http://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/what-does-haskell-have-to-do-with-c/) (discovered via cpp-next.com). My thought process is that one aspect of functional programming boils down the use of [piecewise defined functions in code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) for branch control (and if you can manage it, tail recursion).

So, my questions:

- Is this "functional"? It appears that way and my interviewers said they had backgrounds in functional programming, but it didn't match what I thought was functional. I see no reason why you couldn't have a logical operator as part of a function - it seems to lend itself nicely to the concept of higher order functions. I just hadn't thought that the use of logical operators was how functional programmers achieved branch control. Right? Wrong? I can see that circuits use logic gates for branch control so I guess this is a similar (related) concept?
- Is there some advantage to using this technique? Is it just language conciseness/a syntax issue, or are there implications in terms of building an interpreter to using this construct?
- Are there any use cases for this technique? Or is it not used very often? Is it used at all? As a self-taught guy I'd never seen it before although that in itself isn't necessarily surprising.

I apologise for jumping over so many languages; I'm simply trying to tie together my understanding across them. Feel free to answer in any language mentioned. I also apologise if I've misunderstood any definitions or am missing something vital here, I've never formally studied computer science.

Comment: Awesome question. Love the structure and the depth you go into +1. Its a shame I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @unutbu and we're into the territory in Gordon's answer. Try `print (None and 7)`. That returns `None` i.e. the value of `f()`. `f()` is evaluated to determine what its value is and then *that* is used to determine what gets returned. If `f()` is evaluated to false in an `and`, `g()` will never be evaluated, which I think is the point, but if `f()` returns true, `g()` will always be evaluated and its value returned. Compare `print(7 and None)` to `print(7 or None)`.

I think...

Comment: I realized moments after posting that I had made an error, so I deleted my comment. I guess I did not remove it soon enough. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @unutbu it's ok. I've been puzzling this one out since said interview...!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your interviewers must have had a "functional background" way back.  It used to be common to write

```
(or (some-condition) (some-side-effect))
```

but in CL and in Scheme implementation that support it, it is much better written with `unless`.  Same goes for `and` vs `when`.

So, to be more concrete -- it's not more functional (and in fact the common use of these things was for one-sided conditionals, which are not functional to begin with); there is no advantage (which becomes very obvious in these languages when you know that things are implemented as macros anyway -- for example, most `or` and `and` implementations expand to an `if`); and any possible use cases should use `when` and `unless` if you have them in your implementation, otherwise it's better to define them as macros than to not use them.

Oh, and you could use a combination of them instead of a two sided `if`, but that would be obfuscatingly ugly.

Comment: thanks, I think than answers it, very interesting. Combined with @Jochen's observations that actually evaluating 0 to false can cause problems I think that explains my misunderstandings! +1

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any issues with the way this code will execute, but it is confusing to read for the uninitiated.  In fact, this kind of syntax is like a Python anti-pattern:  you can do it, but it is in no way Pythonic.

Comment: It is rather Perlish, though. TMTOWTDI is encouraged in Perl and deprecated in Python.

Comment: Agreed.  Perl is exactly what I thought when I saw this.

Comment: I've used this sort of construct in bash too, come to think of it.

Answer (score 5):

`condition and true_branch or false_branch` works in all languages that have short circuting logical operators. On the other hand it's not really a good idea to use in a language where values have a boolean value.

For example

```
zero = (1==0) and 0 or 1   # (1==0) -> False 
zero = (False and 0) or 1  # (False and X) -> X
zero = 0 or 1              # 0 is False in most languages
zero = False or 1 
zero = 1
```

Comment: +1 for a practical reason and because this is also my experience. I came across this problem when trying to implement a "make even" routine (which adds 1 to any odd number) entirely using logical operators in python (hence the erlang in the question), which was a precursor/exploration before asking this. My problem there was that I could handle all positive and negative numbers except zero, which evaluated to false in the wrong place, resulting in it being treated as odd.

Comment: In all languages with short-circuiting and/or, as long as true_branch never returns something that can be interpreted as false.

Answer (score 2):

As Eli said; also, performing control flow purely with logical operators tends to be taught in introductory FP classes -- more as a mind exercise, really, not something that you necessarily want to use IRL. It's always good to be able to translate any control operator down to `if`.

Now, the big difference between FPs and other languages is that, in more functional languages, `if` is actually an expression, not a statement. An `if` block *always* has a value! The C family of languages has a macro version of this -- the `test? consequent : alternative` construct -- but it gets really unreadable if you nest more expressions.

Prior to Python 2.5, if you want to have a control-flow expression in Python you might have to use logical operators. In Python 2.5, though, there *is* an FP-like if-expression syntax, so you can do something like this:

```
(42 if True else 7) + 35
```

See [PEP 308](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html)

Answer (score 2):

You only mention the case where there are exactly 2 expressions to evaluate.  What happens if there are 5?

```
;; returns first true value, evaluating only as many as needed
(or (f x) (g x) (h x) (i x) (j x))
```

Would you nest if-statements?  I'm not sure how I'd do this in Python.  It's *almost* like this:

```
any(c(x) for c in [f, g, h, i, j])
```

except Python's `any` throws away the value and just returns `True`.  (There might be a way to do it with `itertools.dropwhile`, but it seems a little awkward to me.  Or maybe I'm just missing the obvious way.)

(As an aside: I find that Lisp's builtins don't *quite* correspond to what their names are in other languages, which can be confusing.  Lisp's `IF` is like C's ternary operator `?:` or Python's conditional expressions, for example, not their if-statements.  Likewise, Lisp's `OR` is in some ways more like (but not exactly like) Python's `any()`, which only takes 2 expressions.  Since the normal `IF` returns a value already, there's no point in having a separate kind of "if" that can't be used like this, or a separate kind of "or" that only takes two values.  It's already as flexible as the less common variant in other languages.)

I happen to be writing code like this right now, coincidentally, where some of the functions are "go ask some server for an answer", and I want to stop as soon as I get a positive response.  I'd never use `OR` where I really want to say `IF`, but I'd rather say:

```
(setq did-we-pass (or (try-this x)
                      (try-that x)
                      (try-some-other-thing x)
                      (heck-maybe-this-will-work x))
```

than make a big tree of IFs.  Does that qualify as "flow control" or "functional"?  I guess it depends on your definitions.

Comment: The Python equivalent of `(or (f x) (g x) (h x) (i x) (j x))` is `f(x) or g(x) or h(x) or i(x) or j(x)`.

Comment: Gabe: Right, that makes sense.  I guess I was trying to think of a mechanism that accepted an arbitrary number of expressions.

Comment: The Python version would use generators: `results = (c(x) for c in [f, g, h, i, j]); first = next(res for res in results if res)` - or simply a function that returns the first result.

Answer (score 0):

1. It may be considered "functional" in the sense of style of programming that is/was preferred in functional language. There is nothing functional in it otherwise.
2. It's just syntax.
3. It may be sometimes more readable to use or, for example:

   ```
   def foo(bar=None):
       bar = bar or []
       ...
       return bar

   def baz(elems):
       print "You have %s elements." % (len(elems) or "no")
   ```

You could use `bar if bar else []`, but it's quite elaborate.

Comment: The question *was* whether it's considered more functional...  (And it's definitely not.)